# How do I remove the b'' after retrieving data from mysql to Python

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, byte

1. I get the data from MySQL server, and format it into a list of lists.

```
raw_data = read_query(connection, query)
csv_data = []
for row in raw_data:
    row = list(row)
    csv_data.append(row)
```

2. Convert the data into Dataframe, and export as CSV

```
df = pd.DataFrame(csv_data)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

How can I get rid of the **b''** in all columns where it is present? I tried to change encoding='utf-8', the b'' is still there. It seems the dataframe takes the b'' as a string instead of proper byte?

Comment: The columns with b'' all contain string instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.decode`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [b'Hello', b'world']})

          A
0  b'Hello'
1  b'world'


df['A'] = df['A'].str.decode('utf-8')
print(df)

# Output
       A
0  Hello
1  world
```

Comment: Got this error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?` I used it as `object = object.str.decode`

Comment: What is the ouput of `print(type(df['A'].iloc[0]))`. Replace `A` by the name of your column.

Comment: What is `object`?

Comment: `<class 'bytes'>` This is what I get from `print(type(df['A'].iloc[0]))`

Comment: So my code should work. What is your version of Pandas? And what is exactly `object = object.str.decode`?

Comment: In my case, I assigned the header of my dataframe by `df.columns = [header_list]`, to get access to the column, I looped through my header_list and print the column by `df[header]`, it shows the data type of df[header] is **object**

Comment: You probably have numeric columns that have not `str` accessor. Try something like: `df.update(df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda x: x.str.decode('utf-8')))` without your loop, just change the name of your dataframe if needed

Comment: It worked, perfect! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad to read that. I had no more idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Decode the members of `row`.

```
raw_data = read_query(connection, query)
csv_data = []
for row in raw_data:
    row = list(row)
    row = [x.decode() for x in row]
    csv_data.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'